# Simpson's rule of Integration in Python

Tags: python

I have written a code for it, but whatever i try, its not working
Can someone please take a look

```
def y(x):
    y=(x**3+2*x)/(x**2+2*x)

a=int(input("Enter lower limit:"))
b=int(input("Enter higher limit:"))
n=int(input("Enter no. of points:"))
h=1.0*(b-a)/n
x=[a+i*h for i in range(n)]
y=[y(i) for i in x]
I=1.0*(h/3)*(y[0]+y[-1]+4*sum(y[1:-1:2])+2*sum(y[2:-1:2]))
print (I)
```

It shows the error:

```py
I=1.0*(h/3)*(y[0]+y[-1]+4*sum(y[1:-1:2])+2*sum(y[2:-1:2]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Your function `y`  doesn't actually return anything, the list is full of `None`. Note that you should do basic debugging *before* asking here, and give a [mre].

Comment: Also it is bad practice to define a function only to later overwrite it with a value.

Comment: `None` is a special value in Python that means a variable doesn't have a value. The line with the error has many places where this error could occur. I suggest you add `print()` statements to print out parts of the expression to see what the values are. For example `print(h)`, `print(y)`, `print(y[0])`, etc. These will help you figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `return` in your function:

```py
def y(x):
    return (x**3+2*x)/(x**2+2*x)

a=int(input("Enter lower limit:"))
b=int(input("Enter higher limit:"))
n=int(input("Enter no. of points:"))
h=1.0*(b-a)/n
x=[a+i*h for i in range(n)]
y=[y(i) for i in x]
I=1.0*(h/3)*(y[0]+y[-1]+4*sum(y[1:-1:2])+2*sum(y[2:-1:2]))
print(I)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that a value in the expression is `None`. This is a special value in Python that represents that there is no value. Since the expression is so large, you can find the problem by printing out parts of the expression, such as `print(h)` or `print(y)` to find the problem. Specifically, look at these lines from your code with an added `print(y)`:

```
def y(x):
    y=(x**3+2*x)/(x**2+2*x)


y=[y(i) for i in x]
print(y)
```

This will print out something like

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

This is because the `y()` function is missing a `return` statement. To fix the problem, just add `return`:

```
def y(x):
    return (x**3+2*x)/(x**2+2*x)
```

Tip: You name a function `y` and later assign `y` to a list. This reuse of a single name for two different things can cause problems later if you try to change this code. I suggest renaming the function to `f`:

```
def f(x):
    return (x**3+2*x)/(x**2+2*x)

y=[f(i) for i in x]
```